# Cypher performance - dbHits vs execution time

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

After managing to get everything working with spatial plugin now I'm optimising my query to get the best out of it

At the beginning the query took like 10 seconds

After finding this question 
[Improve Neo4j Cypher Performance On Lengthy Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154066/improve-neo4j-cypher-performance-on-lengthy-match)
 I got the query to run in 3 seconds but still it had like 140k dbHits

I tried to break the query even into more matches and after that I got it to 50k dbHits but strangely the execution time actually was increased

Can someone explain me if there's a direct relation between dbHits and execution time?

Here is an example of my query(it's a short version of the query, the real query is a lot bigger)

```
START user=node(1), friend=node:userPosition("withinDistance:[0.003000,0.003000,10.000000]") 
WHERE friend.birthYear >= 1952 AND friend.birthYear <= 1977
WITH DISTINCT friend, user
MATCH (user)-[:SPEAKS]->(:Language)<-[:SPEAKS]-(friend)
WITH friend, user
MATCH (user)-[:EXPECTS]->(expectedObligatoryAnswers:Answer {isOptional : 0}))<-[:ANSWERED]-(friend)
WITH friend, user,COUNT(DISTINCT expectedObligatoryAnswers.questionId) AS countExpectedObligatoryAnswers
WHERE (countExpectedObligatoryAnswers = 2)
RETURN friend
LIMIT 3;
```

In the bigger query this got 3 sec of execution time but 140k of dbHits

After breaking the first two matches

```
MATCH (user)-[:SPEAKS]->(lang:Language)
WITH user, friend, lang
MATCH (lang)<-[:SPEAKS]-(friend)
WITH friend, user
MATCH (user)-[:EXPECTS]->(expectedObligatoryAnswers:Answer {isOptional : 0}))
WITH friend, user, expectedObligatoryAnswers
MATCH (expectedObligatoryAnswers)<-[:ANSWERED]-(friend)
```

This takes like 1/3 of dbHits (50k) but the execution time is increased like 2 seconds

Is there an in-progress documentation for profiling cypher?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that splitting the first match improves performance? Have you tried reversing the directions of the matches? Lots of permutations possible there.

Comment: @JimBiard No I didn't try it with the first one, my main question is if that if actually reducing dbHits is always going to give you a faster execution comparing to a higher dbHits or not.